# What could be causing the error com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError when I use TomCat?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

**When trying to initialize the server on TomCat, it gives this error in the console:**

```
GRAVE: Critical error during deployment: 
com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.jboss.weld.security.GetDeclaredMethodAction does not implement the requested interface java.security.PrivilegedAction
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2256)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3990)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3994)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4878)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCastCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:74)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.getClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:204)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:742)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:768)
    at com.sun.faces.cdi.CdiUtils.getBeanReferenceByType(CdiUtils.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.cdi.CdiUtils.getBeanReference(CdiUtils.java:216)
    at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.Version.isJsf23(Version.java:90)
    at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.ExpressionLanguage.addELResolver(ExpressionLanguage.java:160)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.addELResolver(ApplicationImpl.java:245)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.jsf.WeldApplication.<init>(WeldApplication.java:73)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.jsf.WeldApplicationFactory.getApplication(WeldApplicationFactory.java:47)
    at com.sun.faces.application.InjectionApplicationFactory.getApplication(InjectionApplicationFactory.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl.<init>(ClientWindowFactoryImpl.java:63)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:347)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:482)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:372)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:224)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:303)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.lambda$verifyFactoriesExist$0(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:327)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:321)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:235)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.lambda$initialize$0(ConfigManager.java:318)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:720)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:316)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4439)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4899)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1364)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1354)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.jboss.weld.security.GetDeclaredMethodAction does not implement the requested interface java.security.PrivilegedAction
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at com.sun.faces.cdi.CdiExtension$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:347)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
    at org.jboss.weld.security.NewInstanceAction.run(NewInstanceAction.java:33)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:303)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyFactory.create(ClientProxyFactory.java:111)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.createClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:180)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.createClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:170)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.access$100(ClientProxyProvider.java:45)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$CreateClientProxy.load(ClientProxyProvider.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$CreateClientProxy.load(ClientProxyProvider.java:52)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3589)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2374)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2337)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2252)
    ... 48 more

set. 27, 2023 2:35:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.jboss.weld.security.GetDeclaredMethodAction does not implement the requested interface java.security.PrivilegedAction
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4439)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4899)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1364)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1354)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.jboss.weld.security.GetDeclaredMethodAction does not implement the requested interface java.security.PrivilegedAction
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2256)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3990)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3994)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4878)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCastCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:74)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.getClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:204)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:742)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:768)
    at com.sun.faces.cdi.CdiUtils.getBeanReferenceByType(CdiUtils.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.cdi.CdiUtils.getBeanReference(CdiUtils.java:216)
    at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.Version.isJsf23(Version.java:90)
    at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.ExpressionLanguage.addELResolver(ExpressionLanguage.java:160)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.addELResolver(ApplicationImpl.java:245)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.jsf.WeldApplication.<init>(WeldApplication.java:73)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.jsf.WeldApplicationFactory.getApplication(WeldApplicationFactory.java:47)
    at com.sun.faces.application.InjectionApplicationFactory.getApplication(InjectionApplicationFactory.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl.<init>(ClientWindowFactoryImpl.java:63)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:347)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:482)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:372)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:224)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:303)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.lambda$verifyFactoriesExist$0(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:327)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:321)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:235)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.lambda$initialize$0(ConfigManager.java:318)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:720)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:316)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:229)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.jboss.weld.security.GetDeclaredMethodAction does not implement the requested interface java.security.PrivilegedAction
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at com.sun.faces.cdi.CdiExtension$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:347)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
    at org.jboss.weld.security.NewInstanceAction.run(NewInstanceAction.java:33)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:303)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyFactory.create(ClientProxyFactory.java:111)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.createClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:180)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.createClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:170)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.access$100(ClientProxyProvider.java:45)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$CreateClientProxy.load(ClientProxyProvider.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$CreateClientProxy.load(ClientProxyProvider.java:52)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3589)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2374)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2337)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2252)
    ... 48 more
```

**I've searched in various places, and they advised me to update the dependencies in Maven and check for compatibility issues, but I'm still encountering the same error. I'm using Tomcat version 8.5.**

I'm using these dependencies here, and I've updated all of them:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.algaworks</groupId>
    <artifactId>curso-jsf-e-primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>curso-jsf-e-primefaces</name>
    <description>Curso JSF e PrimeFaces</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEnconding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEnconding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.Alpha1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>13.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.27.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.6.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I would like to be able to run my Tomcat server so that I can view my HTML page.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using to run Tomcat?